# Translating a geometry node changes its color

Tags: color, geometry-nodes

I have a pretty simple geometry node based on a plane:
[image]

What it does, it takes an hexagonal polygon as mesh, places it on a grid (yellow hexagons on the picture below - same color than source object), then translates the same point (which gives the red polygons - color of supporting plane).

How come there are 2 colors and not a single one ?
[image]

Link to the Blend file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1jmdsjl7bpq8gbb/Polygones.blend?dl=0

Comment: can u provide blend file?

Comment: Link attached in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, first, i think you wanted to do something like this:

[image]

result:

[image]

you did translate your mesh after instancing. After the instancing it is a "new" mesh. So if you translate that mesh again it will take the material from your plane (which is your GN object), that's why these polygons are red.

You can "verify" this by using attribute separate node xyz with position.

[image]

If you try to access these x,y,z after the instancing you can't access it. Before instancing you can.

Of course now there is a workaround for this with the attribute transfer node.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot ! Indeed I'm a Blender newbie.

Comment: You are welcome. We all started once….

Comment: ...and when Fields are fully functional, we will all have to start again ..:)